# getting all occurences of string and replacing them

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

example text

```
this text will be left alone ##{class1}{arg1;arg2;arg3}## some other text and
another thingie ##{Class2}{]##
```

Currently i'm using this `'/\#\#\{(?P<class>.+)\}\{(?P<args>.+)\}\#\#/i'` to match it, but my problem is that when this regex occurs multiple times, because it will match even the text between the two matched patterns.

And this is the result of my regex `##{ClassName1}{arg1;arg2;arg3}## some other random ##{class2}{}##`.

Is there a more elegant way to extract `##{class1}{arg1;arg2;arg3}##` and `##{Class2}{]##` from the string and replace them with the output from coresponding classes?

I'm using this as to replace them with output from Class1 and Class2 with arguments inbetween the second set of `{}`

---

Note: if the second set of {} is empty that means that no arguments are passed to the class with the name in the first set of {}

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that `.+` is "greedy" — it will consume every character it possibly can, as long as the rest of the pattern can still resolve.

The dirty generic solution is to do `.+?` which will match the fewest characters necessary to satisfy the rest of the pattern, and would work in this case.

But generally it's preferable to write something more specific than `.+` anyway. In your case, would `[^}]+` work? That is, between the `{` and `}` symbols, you can have any number of characters that aren't a closing `}`.

Comment: And a followup note that if you want to allow no characters in the second argument list, `[^}]*` instead of `[^}]+` would be necessary.

Comment: so i came up with this `/\#\#(?P<class>\{.+?[\}]*)(?P<args>\{.+?[\}]*)\#\#/i` it matches everything what i need, but the `<class>` contains `{class1}` for example. But that is just a minor problem. But moving `\{` and `[\}]*` outside of `(?P<class>\{.+?[\}]*)` gives me `}` if matching a `{}` string... damn these regexps ... i guess i will never fully understand them

Comment: and another note... i had to use .+? in the second part of ##{}{}## because the you can pass almost anything as a argument to the class... but i replaced the classname with `\w+?`